# pandas parse dates with two columns and replace a single point to a double point

Tags: python, pandas

this is how i want to read my csv file in:

```
data01 = pd.read_csv('data/file.csv', sep=';', decimal=',', parse_dates=[['date', 'time']])
```

Time is given as *hh.mm.ss* and i want it like this:*hh:mm:ss*
Is there a way to do this inside the pd.read_csv?

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use

```
data01["(insert name of column with time)"].replace({".",":"}
```